# Lambda not deleting DynamoDB records when triggered with Cloud Watch events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to delete items in my Dynamodb table using Cloud Watch event triggered Lambda. This lambda scans the dynamo table and deletes all expired items. My code seems to be working when I test it using the test event in the console (i.e it deletes all the expired items). But when lambda gets triggered automatically using the Cloud Watch event it does not delete, event though I see that the lambda is being triggered.

```
exports.handler = async function () {

var params = {
    TableName: TABLE_NAME
}

try {
    const data = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
    const items = data.Items;

    if (items.length != 0) {

        Promise.all(items.map(async (item) => {
            const expirationDT = new Date(item.ExpiresAt);
            const now = new Date();

            if (now > expirationDT) {
                console.log("Deleting item with otc: " + item.Otc + " and name: " + item.SecretName);

                const deleteParams = {
                    TableName: TABLE_NAME,
                    Key: {
                        "Otc": item.Otc,
                        "SecretName": item.SecretName,
                    },
                };

                try {
                    await docClient.delete(deleteParams).promise();
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log("The Secret was not deleted due to: ", err.message);
                }
            }
        }))
    }

} catch (err) {
    console.log("The items were not able to be scanned due to : ", err.message)
}}
```

***I know using DynamoDB TTL is an option, but I need these deletions to be somewhat precise, and TTL can sometimes take up to 48 hours, and I am aware I can use a filter when retrieving records to counter-act that. Just wondering what's wrong with my code here.***

Answer (score 0):

You need to await `Promise.all` or your lambda will end execution before it resolves

```js
        await Promise.all(items.map(async (item) => {
            const expirationDT = new Date(item.ExpiresAt);
            const now = new Date();
            // ...
```